# Delete grub without losing one of OS

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have Windows 10 and Linux Mint in a dual boot, and want to delete GRUB (I don't like it) and instead open BIOS to choose which operating system to boot with. Is it possible to delete just the GRUB? If is, then how?

Comment: Why don't you set grub as default bootloader where you can choose Mint _or_ Windows?

Comment: Grub is both a bootmanager/menu & boot loader. You cannot delete grub as bootloader without major reconfiguration of a system. If UEFI you can use another boot manager like rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908677/want-to-view-contents-of-boot-efi-in-xubuntu-dont-have-permissions

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS can't choose an OS to boot from; you must replace GRUB with another boot manager when you have multiple operating systems. Some choices are:

- [BURG](https://launchpad.net/burg)
- [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) aka GRUB  (provided for reference)
- [LILO](http://lilo.alioth.debian.org/)     (development stopped in late 2015, problematic with GT, RAID, and BTFS)
- [ReFIND](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)   (themable, EFI/UEFI only, no MBR/BIOS support)
- [Syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Syslinux_Project)
- [systemd-boot aka Gummiboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot)  (EFI/UEFI only, no MBR/BIOS support)